# SubSonic 2.1 using multiple databases

Tags: database, subsonic, connection-string

I want to use SubSonic 2.1 to connect to 2 different databases (each having different tables). What is the best way to do this? What is the best way to seperate the generated code between the 2 databases and how can I switch between databases?

Comment: As a note SubSonic 2.2 is basically a bug fix release for 2.1 and I would recomment using 2.2 for all users targeting 2.1 as the api did not change between 2.1 and 2.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subsonic: dynamic connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968391/subsonic-dynamic-connections)

Answer (score 1):

I do this on quite a few projects with 2.2 and find that i dont need to impliment the "shared connection scope"

I set my class library up with the databases, give all the databases all a different name and namespace and gen it.

Then when i need to call them i am specific about what i am calling

ie

```
SqlQuery q = new Select()
             .From(Tables.Products);
```

becomes

```
SqlQuery q = new Select()
             .From(Data.Database1.Tables.Products);
```

if its still failing i've found i can do the following

```
SqlQuery q = Data.Database1.DB.Select()
             .From(Data.Database1.Tables.Products);
```