# Can't find the SubSonicService section of the application config file

Tags: c#, subsonic, designer, subsonic2.2

When i try to open my MainForm in Visual Studio in the designer, this error pops up instead of the designer of the Visual Studio.

**Can't find the SubSonicService section of the application config file**

```
at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object value)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializePropertyAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement, CodePropertyReferenceExpression propertyReferenceEx, Boolean reportError)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
```

It worked before and there are a lot of other Forms/Controls in the Project and they work. I also can build my project and run it without any problems, it seems just to be the designer.

My app.config has a section of SubSonic and i didn't change it so it should be correct because it worked before.

I use C# with Visual Studio 2005 and .net 2 with SubSonic 2, i can't switch, it's an existing project.

Has anyone a idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to load a subsonic object in the constructor of your main form or any other custom control in it. This is a common error that happen with other objects that don't work within the designer. For this case there is a property DesignMode which you can check:

```
if (!DesignMode)
{
    Product p = new Product(1);
}
```

That said, I would suggest to not rely on the app.config to configure subsonic in windows forms projects. There are different ways to inject a provider into subsonic2 without using a app.config.
In a web project there is always an web.config file that holds most config options for the whole project but in a windows forms app there are other challenges like:

- changing connection string options (different hosts/users) and you probably don't want to store your password in the app.config (at least if you don't use single sign on).
- if you use subsonic in a class library you have to add an subsonic service section to every winforms / console app that uses it.
- runtime connection changes. Maybe you have a test and a production db that you wan't to connect to without closing the app and edit your app.config file.

Look at my answer here: [Subsonic: dynamic connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968391/subsonic-dynamic-connections/968655#968655) how to do this.

(the code isn't from me but the original page is down)

This method works like a charm for me.